# Font Awesome icons doesn't show up on cypress runner container

Tags: html, reactjs, web, cypress, font-awesome

I am currently learning cypress with my own react todo app.

When I run my integration test, my UI icons (loaded via CDN from font awesome) doesn't show up. Therefore my UI Button for deleting a Todo doesn't have width to be visible.

So the click events doesn't work and I get the Error like shown in the screenshot.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7qOC.png)

How can I make sure that my font awesome icons are loaded in my app, can I tell cypress to wait or something? - cuz I guess it ignores the external loaded stylesheet

[screenshot from test code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW4mG.png)

Comment: Hi, have you tried to click with `{ force: true }` parameter as suggested in the error message?

Comment: @Yoshi yeah that works thanks but i would still prefer to see my entire app as it is

Comment: I understand, but that's hard to see without your code and the possibility to test it, I am afraid :)

Comment: Please add your code that you tried.

Comment: I added my test code guys

Answer (score 0):

If you think waiting for the element could help, then you could try something similar as I have for rendering the table:

```
let rounds = 0;
function checkData () {
    rounds += 1;
    // if we got what we wanted
    cy.wait(5000).get('.table-responsive')
        .getTable().then(tableData => {
        cy.log(JSON.stringify(tableData, null, 2));
        if (tableData && tableData.length > 0)
            // break out of the recursive loop
            return;
        // else recurse
        cy.log(`waiting already ${rounds * 5} seconds`);
        if (rounds > 40) return;
        checkData();
    })
}
checkData();
```

Also I use something similar when I wait for a button to be enabled:

```
const clickButtonEnabled = () => {
    cy.get('#analyze').then(($btn) => {
        if ($btn.is(":disabled")) {
            cy.wait(2000);
            cy.log('waiting for button to be enabled');
            clickButtonEnabled();
        } else {
            cy.log('analyze button is enabled');
            cy.wrap($btn).click()
        }
    })
};
clickButtonEnabled();
```

Comment: The element is already there but the external stylesheet which makes my icons visible inside the buttons are not. Nothing from font awesome shows up. The Stylesheet link is this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

Comment: if you expect the stylesheet to be loaded later, why not to try some check for the size of the element? Then if the size is correct you would click.  
I personally rather use the icons not from CDN but installed. I have:
```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
...```
never had any problems.